# Elements sometimes are not located [Selenium, Python]

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, element

I'm using Selenium to automate a process and I am using ChroPath to find Elements like XPath for easier use. But sometimes the elements are not available; example:

[Element that I'm trying to locate](https://prnt.sc/pjbwxi)

[ChroPath](https://prnt.sc/pjbx1l)

```
try:
    P_Captcha_ButtonWait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH("//div[@class='antigate_solver recaptcha in_process']"))))
    print("Captcha is being solved. Waiting 40 seconds...")
    time.sleep(40)
    CaptchaSolved = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='antigate_solver recaptcha solved']")))
    time.sleep(3)
    print("It's rocking!!!!")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/p[3]/button[1]").click()
except:
    P_Email_Verification = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
        By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/label[1]/div[1]/input[1]")))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        "/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/label[1]/div[1]/input[1]").click()
    print("Something went wrong and idk why?")
```

This is the line of Code I have written for the Captcha part and I am actually using Anti-Captcha.com Extension and I want to locate the text that Anti-Captcha gives when it is solving the captcha. It looks like this: [Anti-Captcha](https://prnt.sc/pjc2sd)

Also, the website I'm trying this on is ProtonMail, the page where you verify your self if you're a human or not.

I have already coded the part where you verify your self using E-Mail, but I want Captcha as a main-use and the E-Mail Verification as a backhand in case things go wrong with Captcha.

I have tried researching for locating the element, but the only thing I could find is with an image searcher? 
I have been forced to use PyAutoGui with absolute directions most of the time for some elements like Button clicking or Clicking in certain fields with absolute direction because I couldn't properly find the XPath.

I'd like to know some ways experience users locate elements.

Update:

This is another attempt of me trying to fix the code and trying different methods but still not working.

```
try:
    P_Captcha_ButtonWait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='status'][contains(.,'Solving is in process...')]")))
    if P_Captcha_ButtonWait is True:
        print("Captcha is being solved. Waiting 40 seconds...")
        time.sleep(40)
    CaptchaSolved = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='antigate_solver recaptcha solved'][contains(.,'Solved')]")))
    if CaptchaSolved is True:
        time.sleep(3)
        print("It's rocking!!!!")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                "/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/p[3]/button[1]").click()
except TimeoutException:
#    P_Email_Verification = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
#        By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/label[1]/div[1]/input[1]")))
#    driver.find_element_by_xpath(
#        "/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/label[1]/div[1]/input[1]").click()
    print("Something went wrong and idk why?")
    driver.close()
```

I have made the lines in `except` as comments for now as my main goal is to fix finding the Anti-Captcha Element.

Basically whatever I do, `try` won't run because the Element isn't founded.
I thought to make it work in another way; if Captcha option is available on selection, driver can wait 30-80 seconds until Captcha is solved. (that's how long anti-captcha takes approx most of the times to solve a captcha). But sometimes they take up to 200 seconds so that will run into errors and 'cause the whole script failing. So that's the reason why I want to locate this element, because it's easier and keeps the script running.

Comment: P.S: don't mind the weird prints, I just do weird texts so when I actually see the text getting printed, I get excited and it sounds funny seeing weird stuff popping up when you succeed so.. :)

Comment: @zyrtar : why are you using chropath, insted of that you can create/ write your own xpath ... it's so easy just refer this ... https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/basics-xpath-pritam-maske/

Comment: @orde Hello, if there is any text that makes this thread unprofessional or a waste of time for the reader, please send me an edit so I can review it and make me understand which part is awful. Thanks

Comment: @PritamMaske Because I'm a bit lazy and I found ChroPath in my day one and helped me get through. Thanks for the suggestion regardless!

Comment: @zyrtar: I'm just providing some a (potentially) helpful link to a new contributor.  There's a lot of information in your question, so reducing it to a [mcve] might help with responses.  And it sounds like you are trying to bypass reCaptcha, which can be considered malicious behavior against the target site.  Good luck!

Comment: When "sometimes" XPath expression can't select any element, it might be that the expression relies heavily on hierarchy when in the other hand the document is ment to be a juxtaposition of semantics over a linear information. So, you need to rewrite your XPath expression in order to catch that semantic.